# Output list with first match among two list

Tags: list, tcl, matching

I have two lists in Tcl:

list1

```
{a/1 a/2 b/1 b/2}
```

list2

```
{a b}
```

I wanted to write a code which will check an element from `list2` in `list1` and give the first match and ignores the rest of the matches, basically below output list:

```
a/1 b/1
```

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky bit in this is knowing exactly how the items in list 2 are to be searched for in list 1. I'm going to assume they're fairly simple strings and that we can just glob match for them (as if with `string match`). That's a case that `lsearch` supports by default, allowing us to use a pretty simple bit of code:

```
proc FirstMatches {haystackList needlesList} {
    lmap needle $needlesList {
        lsearch -inline $haystackList $needle*
    }
}
puts [FirstMatches {a/1 a/2 b/1 b/2} {a b}]
```

The `lmap` just runs its body (as with `foreach`) for every needle in `$needleList` and collects the results of that into a list. It's perfect here.